# AWS EC2 phpMyAdmin stopped working after allowing permission for html directory in httpd.conf file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have setup EC2 linux 2 instance and install phpMyAdmin on it. And uploaded my site in html folder. Everything is working fine except inner pages of site.
For that i have updated 
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file

replace overwrite None to All for "/var/www/html" directory.

After replacing phpMyAdmin stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Let me attempt:

1. When you say "Everything is working fine except inner pages of site" what do the error logs of your web-server say? Or what HTTP error code/message do you see in the browser?

   - *To check the error logs on the EC2 instance, first login and then try to find the error log. One of the following command would work in case you need to find the location of the error logs.*
   - `grep ErrorLog /usr/local/etc/apache22/httpd.conf`
   - `grep ErrorLog /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
   - `grep ErrorLog /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
   - *To check in the browser, press F12 and then Network Tab to find the error message, otherwise simply `curl -I {some_url_without_curly_braces}` and this will give you the HTTP error code*
2. Are you able to connect to the DB from the instance?
3. Finally, I believe what you are trying to setup is similar to [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html). If yes, then please follow the same and this should fix all your issues.